# Выдает ошибку при переборе .children

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть задание:

> Функция должна перебрать все дочерние элементы элемента `where`
>    и вернуть массив, состоящий из тех дочерних элементов
>    следующим соседом которых является элемент с тегом `P`. Рекурсия - по желанию

```
@param {Element} where - где искать
@return {Array<Element>}
```

Пример для html

```
<div></div><p></p><a></a><span></span><p></p>
```

функция должна вернуть: `[div, span]`, т.к. следующим соседом этих элементов является элемент с тегом `P`

Вот мой код:

```
    function findAllPSiblings(where) {
    var children = where.children
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].nextElementSibling.nodeName = 'P') {
            arr.push(children[i])
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Однако, при вызове функции `findAllPSiblings(body)` консоль (Firefox) выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: `children[i].nextElementSibling` is `null`; can't access its "`nodeName`" property

В Google то же самое. Что делать? Почему не работает?

Comment: когда вы доходите до последнего элемента на уровне, то пытаетесь обратиться к следующему соседу `nextElementSibling`, которого не существует (т.к. элемент-то последний был). Оно возвращает `null`, у которого в свою очередь вы просите `nodeName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же текст ошибки явно говорит, почему не работает.

> children[i].nextElementSibling is null; can't access its "nodeName" property

`children[i].nextElementSibling` имеет значение `null` и вы не можете обратиться к свойству `nodeName`.

Возникает же эта ошибка не последней итерации по массиву дочерних элементов. Когда `i` равно `children.length - 1`. На данной итерации элемент является **последним** и он заведомо не имеет `nextElementSibling`, отсюда и появляется это `null` значение и последующая ошибка обращения к свойству.

Используйте цикл до `< children.length - 1`